# Send file with jQuery using

Tags: jquery

I have this form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="input" name="name">
</form>
```

I would like to send this file input in jQuery to a PHP page:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    var data = new FormData();
    $.each($(':file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        data.append('file', file);
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The code above works but how can I have another `input` and send it in the same time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` method of FormData object can also be used to append regular parameters values with files.

It is a key-value pair where key is parameter name and value is parameter value.

```
data.append('pName', 'pValue');
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)